# .sh files default to read-only on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, shell

I am learning my way through shell scripts and just created one with vim.
Every file I create with `.sh` extension seems to be defaulting to read-only mode for every group in the `ls -l` command. I have tried creating files with several editors and in several locations and always get the same result.

So my question is, I know i can `chmod` the files so i can execute them, but is there something i can do to create them executable already and not change every single one of them?

Comment: My guess is that is a security feature and you can't. But my guess might be totally wrong :)

Comment: Do other files start executable? Do you have reason to believe this is limited to `.sh` files? You can look at `umask` for default permissions of files created via shell tools at least (I don't know if OS X tools use `umask` or not).

Comment: I never had such problems with files `code`.py`code` or `code`.c`code`for example, if that is what your are asking.

Answer (score 1):

As with any UNIX-like system, file creation is affected by the `umask`, which masks out file access bits when files are created.

You can change the default `umask` by editing the shell start-up configuration files, however I wouldn't recommend doing that.

If you want to change it so that all files you create have the executable bit set by default, then what about files that are not executable?  I have always worked on shell scripts with the edit, `chmod`, run cycle and I don't feel it's a big problem.

Comment: And you only have to set the execute bit once.

Comment: Since I am learning I must ask: what you are saying is that i can make such a command that creates the file and automatically changes permissions or i must edit and then chmod?

Comment: @Cesar Yes you can, however I have never done so in 25+ years of using UNIX-like systems.